# MS Access 2010 - docmd.printout not printing specified number of copies

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm almost to conclude it is a bug in MS Access. I am at the end of my string to know what to try next.

Here are my steps:

1. Create new, blank 2010 format Access Database
2. Create new report in database with no data source and only one label just so that there is something to print.
3. Print Preview the report.
4. Press Ctrl+G to bring up the immediate window
5. Type `docmd.PrintOut,,,,10` and press enter.
6. Only one copy prints out!

I have done the same thing in my existing rather large database application and no matter what I do I can't get Access to print out more than one copy! There is one exception to this; there is ONE report that will work as normal and I can print out as many copies as I want. I have yet to find another report that works besides this one.

To make it even stranger, when I preview the report, click print on the ribbon and enter a quantity to print, I still only get one copy!

Does anyone have any other ideas of what to try or what the issue might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am getting the same results that you report. As a work around, you could bind the report to a "numbers" table, that is, a table with integers from 1 to maximum required, and set the from and to pages, rather than number of copies.

Comment: That is a good idea. It would be quite a bit of work to do this to all of the reports in my database as there are quite a few. It is interesting that you are getting the same results that I am though.

Comment: No it wouldn't :) You can set the record source programatically with VBA.

Comment: good thought...the problem is that my reports already have a record source set. I would have to intelligently add a table to it...That could get really messy! ...I would also probably need to add a new section to some of them that would force a new page... Wow, talk about messy! Or am I missing an easier way to do it?

Comment: Does the printout method not work when the report is already bound? I find that as long as the recordset returns more than one record, you can print a number of copies for any page(s).