# DoCmd.PrintOut does only Print one copy

Tags: vba, ms-access

I saw that there is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305363/ms-access-2010-docmd-printout-not-printing-specified-number-of-copies) as mine but the workaround that is given there is not a possible way for me.
I have to print up to 1000 or more.

```
 DoCmd.OpenReport Report, acViewReport 'Open report
 DoCmd.PrintOut , , , acHigh, copys' Print report
```

(As copys I have specified the amount of copys.)

Did I do something wrong?

Is there an other way to print the Report out?

Thanks for any help.

complete Code:

```
Private Sub cmd_openreport_Click()

'Set Variables
Dim Report
Dim Etikette
Dim Copyes As String
Dim SQLString
Dim SQLString2


DoCmd.SetWarnings False 'Turns Off Warnings

Etikette = comb_etiketten_auswahl 'Etikette Equals the             comb_etiketten_auswahl value
Report = comb_etiketten_layout 'Report equals the value in the dropdown list
Copyes = Forms!frm_Hauptmenu!comb_etiketten_auswahl.Column(1)


'If The Etiketten Dropdown is empty message to client
If Etikette <> "" Then

'Do Nothing/Continue

Else
MsgBox "Bitte wählen Sie einen Datensatz aus"
Exit Sub

End If


'If The Report Dropdown is empty message to client
If Report <> "" Then

'Do Nothing (because dropdown is mot empty)

Else
MsgBox "Bitte wählen Sie ein Etikettenlayout aus"
Exit Sub

End If

MsgBox anzahl
'If Amount of copies is less than 1 message to client
If anzahl > 0 Then


On Error GoTo Error_MayCauseAnError
    DoCmd.OpenReport Report, acViewReport 'Open report
    DoCmd.PrintOut , , , , Copyes
    DoCmd.Close Report ' Close the Report
```

**EDIT :**

**This question is Irelevant and does not have a purpose anymore!
it was an internal script mistake!**

Comment: Please specify why the workaround is not possible for you. The amount of prints is irrelevant.

Comment: Try this [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/sheets-printout-method-excel)
`DoCMD.PrintOut From:=2, To:=3, Copies:=3`

Comment: That did not work @nishitdey :(

Comment: Then it is out of my reach :(. Sorry. Did you go to the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/sheets-printout-method-excel) link

Comment: yes i've been there but nothing usefull found...

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you declared `copyes` as Variant?

Reading `PrintOut` documentation, I found the following:

**Name**    Copies

**Required/Optional**   Optional

**Data Type**   Variant

**Description**  The number of copies to print. If you leave this argument blank, the default (1) is assumed.

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/docmd-printout-method-access

Also, try using a value instead of a variable just for testing.

---

When you use functions is really important to read the function documentation, to know what kind of variables this function (or procedure) expects.
In this case, this function uses a `Variant` variable (Don't know why), then you should provide a `Variant` object.
Let me give you an example.

You have a drink machine.
Let's think about money in terms of variants. `paper` and `metal`.
Your drink machine only accepts `paper` as money. If you try to insert `metal` (coins), your machine will give an error. 
In this case you need to provide the specific kind of money that your drink machine accepts.

Hope this clarifications let you understand better the issue and help you to read the documentation of the functions or procedure you are using.

Comment: yes copys is a variable 
It does the same if I just type in 12
(the variant is correct all the time i checked that with a msgbox)

Comment: I mean... `copys` variable type is `Variant`?

Comment: `Dim Copyes As String` should be `Dim Copyes As Variant`

Comment: oh okay i'll try that. what is the difference? just so i understand the code              ;-)

Comment: hey @David G.  thanks for the help with the variant that works now with the 100 copys but i get an error at the end when i close my report... can't tell why... any ideas there?

Comment: okay I made a stupid mistake^^ thanks for the help @all it works now.

Comment: Updated my answer trying to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I understand why you have "Copies" right after "PrintOut". All you want is to print a certain number of copies, right? You can simply put

```
DoCmd.PrintOut , , , , copys 'Print report
```

Alternatively, you should also be able to just write

```
DoCmd.PrintOut Copies:=copys 'Print report
```

You don't need to write acHigh as that is the default value

Comment: thanks for the awnser. Im sorry but i had to correct my question. I used you'r first option... but thats the one that does not work... it does only print one copy...

Comment: I think you should show us a bit more of the code so we can see where you declare copys and update its value

Comment: Have you tried  "Dim Copyes As Variant" like David suggested?